# Converting PDF Pages to images using Imagick Changes the color

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick, color-space

I am using Imagick PHP extension to convert PDF files into Images (JPG, PNG) But every time it converts the file, The color of the output images changes with brightness.
I have tried many solutions with Imagick but everytime same result or differnt but not exact result like the original file

[image]

Attached is the picture which original and resultant version. upper one is the original color, lower one is the generated color.

Any suggestions from experts who have faced the same issue?? I am trying to convert this in Laravel. Solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64608519/convert-cmyk-pdf-to-srgb-jpg-using-php-and-imagick) help in your case? Remember, you didn't give us an example PDF, so we cannot test anything ourselves, but it looks similar to your problem. I do believe this is a color space issue.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for your reply, I will try with that solution. incase you want to check the pdf file. Here I uploaded it. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8d53336b0ff2e0c981f153cdd460838020230928100925/359240

Comment: Post your PDF file (zip it first).

Comment: Likely you need to assign an sRGB profile or your PDF has an imbedded image that is using a different color profile or your color profile is being stripped.